# Different source files in Google and Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, view-source

I see different source files when I view source on browser versus checking on Facebook debugger tool. Many tags are missing in the latter to be precise.

Sample urls:

View source: view-source:https://justdoc.com/medicine/surfaz-sn-cream

Facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fjustdoc.com%2Fmedicine%2Fsurfaz-sn-cream

As you can see, many tags including the og tags are not visible in the version that Facebook sees.

Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Well, most likely your system _is_ responding differently, probably based on the requesting User-Agent or something like that.